# Is it possible to achieve Buffalo Plaid Texture with Checker Node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]

Is it possible to achieve something like this with procedural texture nodes like Checker and/or Brick?

Regards,
Anusha

Answer (score 18):

This one will allow you to change size and any of the three colors with only one node.

[image: final_1]

[image: final]

### EDIT:

I've improved this method so it's now possible to group it and use it as just one node with all the controls:

[image: short]

And this is what is grouped:

[image: group]

What is basically doing is generating black-gray-white pattern, assign RGB values to these colors by Color Ramp than separating them and allow to change them.

### Blend file:

[image]

### First Answer:

I don't know if this is the simplest way, but you can make something like this using two **Wave Textures**.

[image: nodes]

**Value node** controls checker size and **Color Ramp** is used to change colors.

Comment: Thanks a ton! And the blend file too!! Double thanks for that!!

Comment: @UVAL If you like this answer consider accepting it and upvoteing.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use the Checker Texture node and a bit of creative UV mapping:

[image: Node Tree]

Will give you this as a result:

[image: Result]

In the multiply node, the bottom socket sets the base color. The intensities of the dark ribbons can be set by changing the grey color sockets of the checker texture. And the number of ribbons can be set in the mapping nodes (currently they are set to 10).